# Dynamically bind a grid (object not set to an instance of an object) error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have created grid dynamically and wanted to bind it.

I wanted to place grid in tabpanel.

I made following code for this purpose:

```
Protected Sub TabContainer1_ActiveTabChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    Handles TabContainer1.ActiveTabChanged
                Dim actTab As String = TabContainer1.ActiveTab.ID.ToString()
                Dim gv As GridView

                ds = gc.GetDataToListBinder("select * from ParameterOnline where TabName='Courts'")

                If actTab = "Panel_Courts" Then
                    gv.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
                    TabContainer1.ActiveTab.Controls.Add(gv)
                End If


            End Sub
```

But its giving me error:

```
object not set to an instance of an object
```

By debugging i seen the dataset ds, but it is having all the necessary values in it.

I am not understanding where i am making mistake?

Answer in c# will also help me.

**EDIT:**

On `gv.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)` line i am getting error.

Comment: On which statement you are getting this error?

Comment: gv.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the `gridview` but not instanstiating it. This article of [creating gridview dynamically](http://asp-net-web-forms-4-0.blogspot.com/2013/01/creating-gridview-programmatically-in_10.html) will helpful.

Change

```
Dim gv As GridView
```

To

```
Dim gv As GridView =  New GridView()
```

Comment: means? please give me example to understand

Comment: Check my updated answer with an example

Comment: my another problem is that, now grid is displayed, two time (may be due to postback), when i add if condition stating if not postback then , bind the grid, its not getting binded single time. how can i overcome this?

Comment: You can put check if !PostBack or check if your actTab already has it.

Comment: but with !postback, grid is not getting binded single time also

Answer (score 1):

use`New` keyword to instantiate your gridview

change your code:

```
Dim gv As GridView
```

into this code:

```
Dim gv As New GridView()
```

Check out this [Gridview constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.gridview.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Hope this will help you to over come this roadblock.